# Apache ProxyPass Load Balance ALL URL's

Tags: apache, http, httpd.conf, httpserver

Using Apache HTTP Server, how do I load balance all URL's, not just root "/" or some sub-directories under root like "/css", but absolutely everything to a balanced backend?

My config will only route the literal root URL "/" but other URL's are not covered, do I need to use a regex?

Relevant config:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember https://server1:8443
    BalancerMember https://server2:8443
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass "/" "balancer://mycluster"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "balancer://mycluster"
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache access_log (notice /css receives a 500 response):

```
172.18.0.1 - - [10/May/2017:20:22:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 196
172.18.0.1 - - [10/May/2017:20:22:58 +0000] "GET /css HTTP/1.1" 500 528
```

Apache error_log:

```
[Wed May 10 20:22:58.607433 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 9:tid 140682836559616] [client 172.18.0.1:35304] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /css. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ProxyPass / .... is enough to proxy everything, but make sure you match slashes, specifying "balancer://mycluster" is incorrect, and you need to match slashes back and forth, so if your origin ends in slash the target also ends in slash, plus in this case balancer://mycluster is really balancer://mycluster/

```
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
```

Comment: Odd, I had it like this before and it didn't work. Now it does! Thanks

Comment: Do you also need to specify the trailing slash in the <Proxy> tag itself?

Comment: I just posted a similar question, though I am needing the origin to be a subdirectory, not root.

Comment: @kojow7 change the uri specified, there is no issue.